# AWS Mobile Hub and Xamarin.Droid

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, xamarin, xamarin.android, amazon-dynamodb

firstly I'm very new to AWS, and I'm interested in authenticating users with Facebook login SDK (that is already setup in my project) and store data to DynamoDB respectively.
I've already setup the AWS Mobile Hub by configuring the Facebook sign-up provider and create Protected DynamoDB tables.

Upon when I want to integrate the hub itself can only create Swift, Objective-C, and Android Studio packages to get me started. So from there I assume that for Xamarin I need to go the hard way.

From this point on what can you suggest me to do in order to get what I've set in Mobile Hub up and running?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have some good Xamarin samples in our AWS Labs repository, including Cognito Identity and Sync.

You can check them out here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples

Comment: Please provide some more info in this answer by explaining the concepts behind the answer or snippets of relevant code than making us to follow the link.